# Java count that replaces every number divisible by 3 to hoppity, and every number divisible by 5 to hop

Tags: java

Java count that replaces every number divisible by 3 to hoppity, and every number divisible by 5 to hop.

```
public class Hoppity {

     public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int count = 1;

      while(count <= 25) {
         System.out.println(count);
         count++;
      }

      if (count % 3==0) {
         System.out.println("Hop");
      }
      else if (count % 5==0) {
         System.out.println("Hoppity");
      }


   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not output anything, other than the numbers 1 through to 25.

By the time you get to the `System.out.println` statements, `count` will be 26, which divides neither 3 nor 5.

The solution? Put the `if` statements inside the `while` loop. Better still, prevent bugs like this by using a `for` loop, with the `count` variable scoped inside. (`for (int count = 1; count <= 25; ++count){...}`). Then `count` will be inaccessible outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I'd say, figure it out. But if you are really stuck. Your if was outside the loop. Mind the braces.

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    int count = 1;

    while(count <= 25) {

       if (count % 3==0) {
         System.out.println("Hop");
       }else if (count % 5==0) {
         System.out.println("Hoppity");
       }else{
         System.out.println(count);
       }
    count++;
   }//end while
}//end main
```

Comment: You ought to explain why you've decided that 15 will print "Hop" rather than "Hop\nHoppity".

Comment: That's true. OP didn't talk about the desired behavior there. I figured I'd let he or she figure it out.

Comment: I can sympathise with that. This answer is useful, +1.